# how to close the dropdown button when user click white space?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I would like to close dropdown button when user click a outside space. How to control it ?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-as5io9?file=index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add click event listener to the window.

When the window is clicked, the listener will set the `checked` of checkbox to false and close the dropdown menu.

Here is the code:

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector('#delete-drop-down');

window.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  checkbox.checked = false;
});


checkbox.addEventListener('click', event=>{
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

`event.stopPropagation()` stops the click event on checkbox propagate to the window. So that the dropdown menu will not be closed immediately。

Answer (score 0):

Done using Javascript
added some CSS class and to close the dropdown when clicking outside is done by creating an invisible div id (invisible) and by using js changing the class of dropdown such that it becomes invisible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8qih3q?file=style.scss,index.html,index.js

Comment: simple and works ! Thanks !

Comment: You're Welcome, Goodluck